# Text Input Box With Instant Content Duplication

Tags: javascript, input, yui

I want to have users be able to enter data into a text box and instantly have that text appear in another div as content with a character limit on the input box.

Much like how SO does it when asking a question but for a different application.

I am using the YUI3 framework if that makes any difference.

Unfortunately I don't know where to start so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use 'onkeyup' and it worked properly.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('text1').value">

<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onchange="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('text1').value">

<div id="div1">
</div>
```

But I would place a function in the onChange event instead of writing the code in the tag.

Comment: Wow I figured it would be simple but was not expecting that :)

Comment: After testing I noticed that it only works once you click out of the box. The others that I have seen change the other div while your typing.